# How to send MULTIPLE params with useHistory hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

`history.push({pathname: '/search?', state: {param1: 'value1'}})` this doesn't work. It just redirects to /search

`history.push('/search?', {param1: 'value1'})` this doesn't work.

`history.push('/search?', ['param1=value1'])` this doesn't work.

`history.push('/search?', [... 'param1=value1'])` this doesn't work.

`history.push('/search?', state: {param1: 'value1'})` this doesn't work.

The only thing that works is this: `history.push('/search?param1=value1')`.

But I need to dynamically send multiple params. How do I do that? The official documentation shows the first example with an object, but it's not working for me. I am using functional components by the way.

Comment: Please clarify ***exactly*** what you are trying to send. Are you trying to send route state, i.e. the first example, or are you trying to add queryString parameters, i.e. your last example? What is the dynamic aspect for what you are trying to do? What is the issue? What isn't working? Can you include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows both what/how you are sending this data ***and*** how you are receiving it, and the route that handles this path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to dynamically get/set the queryString parameters of the URL.

None of the examples you've shared work because the second argument to `history.push` is route state.

```
history.push(path|To, [state])
```

Trying to pass queryString parameters in the second argument doesn't work.

Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to construct a `searchParams` object that you can then update the params of, to be used in the `history.push` method. This method persists any existing queryString parameters.

Example:

```
const { search } = useLocation();

...

// get the search params for the current location
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);

// update params as necessary, i.e. set/delete
searchParams.set("param1", "value1");
searchParams.set("param2", "value2");
searchParams.set("param3", "value3");

// push new route using to object
history.push({
  pathname: "/search",
  search: searchParams.toString(),
});
```

OFC, if you don't need this level of control and just need to inject the three dynamic values you could just use a template string.

```
history.push(`/search?param1=${value1}&param2=${value2}&param3=${value3}`);
```

Comment: Does `searchParams.set()` work with multiple params? Your last example is only meant for one parameter. I need to dynamically be able to set multiple parameters. For example if the person selects a diet value, I need to add diet=value to the route. If he selects  diet, type, whatever, I need to dynamically add those 3 params and their values to the route. Right now I am just using the Link module and I am extracting the array of params and joining them into a string, but this feels too unprofessional.

Comment: Here's what it looks like: 
`<Link to={`/search?title=${ title === "" ? prevValue : title}${filters.length > 1 ? filters.join("&").slice(1) : ""}`}>Apply & Search</Link>`

Comment: I'm updating an array State for each input or selection and then joining them to form the URL path.

Comment: @user17144382 You can set, delete, append, etc... as many queryString parameters as you need for your code/logic. Yes, `searchParams.set` only sets one param at-a-time, so if you need to set others you just make more `.set` calls. I'll update the examples for handling three queryString params.

Comment: Do you mind telling me what is a route state? I'll try using the searchParams tomorrow, but is there a way to use a State and update these searchParams inside the State, and then just extract them into the history.push()? Also, what do you think about my Link solution? Do you like it?

Comment: @user17144382 Route state is just another way to send data from one page to another. It has the benefit of not being exposed to the UI, but the downside of only existing during the route transition. If you reload the page on the receiving end the route state is lost. Route state is ***very*** transient. Your link solution is similar to the template string solution I suggested. It looks like it should work.

Comment: Your solution works perfect! It simplifies the code a lot, and it's also clean and dynamic, just what I wanted! Perfect. Thank you man.

Comment: @user17144382 Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
history.push('/search?param1=value1&param2=value2')
```

Comment: I need to be able to dynamically push params. Is the history object made for only 1 param? This is ridiculous.